# ODBC SQLBindCol() has wrong pointer, but it works. How is this possible?

Tags: c++, c, database, odbc

When I execute a ODBC application, I was able to do it without any problem.
But, once I checked the tracelog, I found very weird values in pointer assignment.

Here is some part of tracelog.

```
WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLGetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  11 <SQL_ATTR_RETRIEVE_DATA>
        SQLPOINTER          0x000000000A55EF90
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0000000000000000

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLGetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  11 <SQL_ATTR_RETRIEVE_DATA>
        SQLPOINTER          0x000000000A55EF90 (1) <SQL_RD_ON>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 
        SQLINTEGER *        0x0000000000000000

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLSetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  11 <SQL_ATTR_RETRIEVE_DATA>
        SQLPOINTER                 1 <SQL_RD_ON>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  11 <SQL_ATTR_RETRIEVE_DATA>
        SQLPOINTER                 1 <SQL_RD_ON>
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLSetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  23 <SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_OFFSET_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x00000000076FE5D0
        SQLINTEGER                  -4 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                  23 <SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_OFFSET_PTR>
        SQLPOINTER          0x00000000076FE5D0
        SQLINTEGER                  -4 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLBindCol 
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x0000000000000098
        SQLLEN                   256
        SQLLEN *            0x0000000000000090

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLBindCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x0000000000000098
        SQLLEN                   256
        SQLLEN *            0x0000000000000090 (BADMEM)

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLBindCol 
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x00000000000001A8
        SQLLEN                   201
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000000001A0

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLBindCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x00000000000001A8
        SQLLEN                   201
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000000001A0 (BADMEM)

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLBindCol 
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        3 
        SWORD                      -25 <SQL_C_SBIGINT>
        PTR                0x0000000000000288
        SQLLEN                    20
        SQLLEN *            0x0000000000000280

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLBindCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        3 
        SWORD                      -25 <SQL_C_SBIGINT>
        PTR                0x0000000000000288
        SQLLEN                    20
        SQLLEN *            0x0000000000000280 (BADMEM)

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLBindCol 
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        4 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x00000000000002B0
        SQLLEN                    11
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000000002A8

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLBindCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        4 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x00000000000002B0
        SQLLEN                    11
        SQLLEN *            0x00000000000002A8 (BADMEM)

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLSetStmtAttrW 
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                   9 <SQL_ROWSET_SIZE>
        SQLPOINTER                 1
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHSTMT            0x0000000000C57FD0
        SQLINTEGER                   9 <SQL_ROWSET_SIZE>
        SQLPOINTER                 1
        SQLINTEGER                  -6 

WCCOActrl.exe - 329c-2160   ENTER SQLExtendedFetch 
        HSTMT               0x0000000000C57FD0
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_FETCH_NEXT>
        SQLLEN                     0
        SQLULEN *           0x000000000A55F040
        UWORD *             0x00000000076FC0B0
```

As you can see the PTR in SQLBindCol(), the PTR is wrong value. 
(it must have valid pointer...)

Are there any people who can explain this for me?

It works very well on "mysql odbc driver" but, not on my own driver.

How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to the magic world of the Undefined Behaviour where everything is possible.